# Objective C - Adding contacts to send SMS/Email

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, sms

I'm trying to create a custom sms/email sending view (I don't think i can use the regular SMS/Email API's since i'm planning on calling a server to send these emails and sms messages - meaning no instant sending so apple's api won't do).

The issue i'm facing:

- Using the contacts bar the way apple uses it - writing a list of all the contacts needed in a way which makes the bar a "dynamic" contacts bar, which allows the user to add with completion or a "+" button which opens a people image picker view, and change the size of the bar in a very unique and nice way for each contact added.

I saw this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553301/implement-add-contact-as-in-iphone-sms-app), but the project is archived and not relevant any more i guess.

IS there any source which has already implemented this? or should i face the fact i will have to implement it from scratch?

Comment: Possibly something like this: https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField ?

Comment: @benhameen Thanks! this might do the trick, but i'm trying to make it work and i really don't know if i'm in the right direction. i saw the example they gave but they did not show how to combine it with the main view or anything of that sort. do you know where can i find such an example? do you have one and you would like to share? thanks once again...